# What does this Django migration error message mean?

Tags: django, django-models

When I try to create migrations for the Django models shown below, I'm getting an error message I don't understand.  I am trying to model a website member who can add one or more other members as either friends or followers.  In addition, a member can block any other member.  Here are my models:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    FRIEND = "friend_of"
    FOLLOWS = "follows"
    RELATION_TYPES = ((FRIEND, "friend"), (FOLLOWS, "follower"))

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    relations = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self", choices=RELATION_TYPES, through="MemberRelation"
    )
    blocks = models.ManyToManyField("self", through="MemberBlock")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name

class MemberRelation(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(
        "Member", related_name="source_member", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    target = models.ForeignKey(
        "Member", related_name="target_member", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    relation = models.CharField(max_length=8)  # Contains Member.FRIEND or .FOLLOWER

    def __str__(self):
        return "Member {} {} member {}".format(self.source, self.relation, self.target)

class MemberBlock(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(
        "Member", related_name="blocker", on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    target = models.ForeignKey(
        "Member", related_name="blocked", on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return "Member {} is blocking Member {}".format(self.source, self.target)
```

I started out with the Member and MemberRelaton classes and my migrations ran without any errors.  But after I add the MemberBlock class and a `blocks` ManyToMany field in my Member model, I'm getting the following error when I run the `makemigrations` command which I don't understand:

```
  You are trying to change the nullable field 'source' on memberrelation to non-nullable without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
  Please select a fix:
  1) Provide a one-off default now...
  2) Ignore for now, and let me handle existing rows with NULL myself (e.g. because you added a RunPython or RunSQL operation to handle NULL values in a previous data migration)
  3) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
  Select an option:
```

I don't understand this error because 1) it's talking about the MemberRelation class now that I've added a MemberBlock class.  It didn't have a problem with this class previously; and 2) the error is saying that the 'source' field is nullable which I don't think it is.

Initially, I declared `blocks` without the `through` option and was getting the same error.  I added the through option because I thought perhaps Django was getting confused by the fact that I have two recursive ManyToMany fields in one class.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
blocked = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False, related_name="members")
```